# body に overflow:hidden; をあてるとなぜスクロールしなくなるのでしょうか？

Tags: css

```
body {
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

この記述を加えると、コンテンツ量に関わらずブラウザのスクロールバーが消えて、
スクロールができなくなるというのは、よく知られたテクニック？の1つかと思います。

私も簡単なモーダルを実装するときによく使っています。

```
body.fixed {
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

みたいな感じで、モーダルを出すときにbodyにclassを加えて`overflow:hidden;`にする簡単なものです。

何も考えずよく使っていたのですが、ふと疑問が湧きました。
**なぜbodyに`overflow:hidden;`が指定されていると、ページのスクロールが無効になるのか？**
　
　
たとえば高さが3000pxにおよぶコンテンツがあったとして、その場合のbody要素の高さも3000pxです。
3000pxの要素に`overflow:hidden;`がかかっていたところで高さは3000pxのまま。
ブラウザwindowの中にその高さを超えるコンテンツものがあったら、スクロールできるのが当然のように思えるのですが、実際にはそうはなりません。

body要素の`overflow:hidden;`はブラウザwindowそのものに指定したのと同じことになるということでしょうか？
　
　
これは別件で質問立てることなのかもしれませんが、
上記の方法で実装したモーダルで、特定の環境下のEdge*のみ、
モーダルを閉じたとき（overflow:hidden;を削除）に、
スクロール位置がページ下に落ちてしまう現象にぶつかりました。
それで実は`overflow:hidden;`のことをよくわかっていないことに気づき
投稿させてもらいました。

body に overflow:hidden; をあてるとなぜスクロールしなくなるのか？
詳しくわかる方がいたら教えてください。

よろしくお願いします。
　
　
*お客さんの閲覧環境でのみ発生していてどのような環境下のEdgeでそうなるのかわかっていません。

Answer (score 18):

`overflow`プロパティが`body`要素に対して設定された場合、その`overflow`プロパティの値は、**`html`要素 (ルート要素) に適用**されます。そして、ルート要素に設定された`overflow`プロパティの値は、**ビューポートへと適用**されます<sup>[1](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visufx.html#propdef-overflow)</sup>。

> #### 11.1.1 Overflow: the ['overflow'](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visufx.html#propdef-overflow) property
>
> UAs must apply the 'overflow' property set on the root element to the
>   viewport. When the root element is an HTML "HTML" element or an XHTML
>   "html" element, and that element has an HTML "BODY" element or an
>   XHTML "body" element as a child, user agents must instead apply the
>   'overflow' property from the first such child element to the viewport,
>   if the value on the root element is 'visible'.

ビューポートとは、簡単にいえば、「ブラウザのウインドウに表示されている領域」を指します<sup>[2](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#viewport)</sup>。ここに`overflow: hidden`が適用されたことにより、`body`要素内に存在する内容は、ビューポートのサイズに合わせて切り取られ、スクロールバーが表示されなくなります。

ただし、`overflow: hidden`を設定したとしても、そのボックスは**スクロールコンテナ**であることに注意してください。スクロールコンテナであるため、依然として JavaScript を用いるなどの方法でスクロールが可能となります。

[CSS Overflow Module Level 3](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-overflow-3/) にて追加された`clip`値を使用すると、スクロールコンテナではないボックスとすることが出来ますが、 2019 年 4 月 25 日現在、`clip`値をサポートしているブラウザはありません<sup>[3](https://caniuse.com/#search=overflow)</sup>。

---

参考:

- [Cascading Style Sheets Level 2 Revision 2 (CSS 2.2) Specification - 11.1.1 Overflow: the 'overflow' property](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visufx.html#propdef-overflow)
- [Cascading Style Sheets Level 2 Revision 2 (CSS 2.2) Specification - 9.1.1 The viewport](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#viewport)
- [Can I use... Support tables for HTML5, CSS3, etc - CSS overflow property](https://caniuse.com/#search=overflow)